# cgi::cookies Needs to return error

Tags: perl, cookies

I'm using CGI::Cookie for my session cookies. I'd like to return an error if the cookie is gone or expired. What I have isn't working. Any ideas??

```
my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
my $cookieID = $cookies{$session_key}->value || error("Your session has   ended. Please logon again");
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not specific enough. What is this code doing and what is it that you expect it to do?

Comment: When using debugging i get this: Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at ... Otherwise as is stated I'd like to return my error page: Your session has ended...

Comment: You're not using "cgi::cookies". Your code clearly shows that you are using "CGI::Cookie". Information like this is important. If you can't be bothered to get information like this right, then why should anyone take the time to help you? Also, using a `&` on a subroutine call in Perl hasn't been necessary since 1994. Where are you getting such outdated advice from?

Comment: Points!!! It looks like you were able to decipher the question. But apparently no one has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, you should be checking `$cookies{$session_key}`.

```
my $session_id_cookie = $cookies{$session_key}
   or error("Your session has ended. Please logon again");

my $session_id = $session_id_cookie->value();
```

Comment: After testing your code the browser prints this over and over: Content-type: text/html Content-type: text/html Content-type: text/html Content-type: text/html Content-type: text/html Content-type: text/html

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: No. But your answer helped me fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
if ( $session_key == $cookies{$session_key}){  } else{ $session_key=""; error("Your session has ended. Please logon again"); exit; }
```

Thanks for the help.